# AmChart is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have json object which i pass to  AmCharts.makeChart() function as a data provider and it shows proper graph in firefox, chrome and ie but not in safari

I also see that json data in console but still graph not comes

I had used amchart.js, serial.js

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. Passing `"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS"` to the AmCharts.makeChart command solved the issue for me. An example graph code would look like this:

```
var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "dark",
    "pathToImages": "amcharts/images/",
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "position": "left",
        "title": "temperature (\xB0C)"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "fillAlphas": 0.4,
        "valueField": "temp"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {},
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN, DD MMMM",
        "cursorPosition": "mouse"
    },
    "categoryField": "time",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "minPeriod": "mm",
        "parseDates": true,
        "title": "date"
    },
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS"
});
```

In my case, the JSON object was created from a mysql database from a php script. The database contained epoch timestamps which I converted into date time format in mysql by using a `FROM_UNIXTIME(time)` select query. This gives me dates like `2014-10-06 22:04:16`. Apparently, Chrome and firefox can handle such date strings natively but safari cannot.

Comment: Excellent! Worked for me, only I had to use a slightly different format for my dates - "YYYY-M-DD",

Answer (score 0):

This is a `Safari` specific issue.

Adding `dataDateFormat`: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS` to `AmCharts.makeChart` solved the issue as answered by Thawn here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26795224/4448807